# Applescript: Convert date into something useful, then perform calculation

Tags: datetime, applescript

I'm trying to create an applescript script that will take a date in the form:

02/20/99

Then, subtract 5 days from the date, and return a date like this:

02/15/99

Here's the basic applescript I have, but, obviously, I'm missing the logic around converting the date into something that I can manipulate (and returning it to something readable by humans).

```
set itemPath to quoted form of POSIX path of theFile

set dateString to do shell script "awk 'NR == 10 {print $3}' " & itemPath & " -"
set myDueDate to dateString - (5 * days)

set theTask to "Pay AMEX bill"

tell application "OmniFocus"
    tell front document
        set theContext to first flattened context where its name = "OFFICE"
        set theProject to first flattened context where its name = "Bookkeeping - PMS"
        tell theProject to make new task with properties {name:theTask, context:theContext, due date:myDueDate}
    end tell
end tell
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these lines should be sufficient for what you need:

```
set dateString to "02/20/99"

set thisDate to date dateString
set fiveDaysEarlier to thisDate - 5 * days
log date string of fiveDaysEarlier
log short date string of fiveDaysEarlier
```

This page has some more examples of the coercions supported when converting strings to objects of date class:
[AppleScript Class Reference: date](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCGECID)

Also, it probably goes without saying, but the string "02/20/99" is not Y2k compliant, so guesses will have to be made somewhere as to which century this date lies in.

Comment: return me "Object not found." number -1728 from date" error

Comment: @chinna_82 It still works for me using both the AppleScript Editor and osascript in terminal on OS X 10.10.3.  What OS X version are you using?  Did you copy and paste the code text exactly to the AppleScript Editor?  Which line of code is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

If you get error "FileMaker Pro got an error: Object not found." number -1728, add my before date. e.g,

set thisDate to my date dateString.

When working inside a tell, I think it needs to access methods outside the tell's scope.